# UNIQUE filter ng-repeat Angular. Hide the duplicate values in columns not whole rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

Lets say I have this object :

```
$scope.men= [
  {
    age: 21,
    name: "John"
  }, 
  {
    age: 21,
    name: "Daenerys"
  },
  {
    age: 21,
    name: "Sansa"
  }
      {
    age: 50,
    name: "Cersei"
  }, 
  {
    age: 50,
    name: "No one"
  },
  {
    age: 50,
    name: "Gregor"
  }];
```

Now in the html view I want to represent a table which will look like this :

```
-------------------
| age   | name    |
-------------------
| 21    | Jhon    |
-------------------
|       | Daenerys|
-------------------
|       | Sansa   |
-------------------
| 50    | Cersei  |
-------------------
|       | Gregor  |
-------------------
```

I tried UI-Angular but it didn't work out well. I need a filter like 'unique' but with a little modification.

EDIT: 
My goal is to hide the duplicate values in the column 'age'.

Comment: Why not just group `$scope.men` by age?

Comment: My goal is to hide the duplicate values in the column 'age' or I did not understand what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple and straightforward solution is to do a ternary check.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="m in men | orderBy:'age'">
          <td>{{men[$index-1].age !== m.age ? m.age : ''}}</td>
          <td>{{m.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Full [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kfNbjK9ZqrfhYvl28C7p?p=preview).

Comment: This does mean that your objects should always be sorted by age,  adding `| orderBy:'age'` to the `ng-repeat` would be better. Btw, `track by $index` is not necessary to expose `$index`

Comment: @NexusDuck Yes you are correct, it is an absolute necessity that the array is ordered by age in order for this solution to work

Comment: It is oredered by age ofc and it works fine for me. That is the idea not to display duplicate values one under another when sorted of course and @PrinceJohn nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your $scope.men to a different object (group by age) and then use ng-repeater on it

```
var obj = {};

$scope.men.forEach(function(men) {
      obj[men.age] = obj[men.age] || [];
      obj[men.age].push(men);
});

$scope.men = obj;

Now you can use ng-repeat over $scope.men
```